# Como fazer botões CRUD no datatables?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-datatables, button

Estou fazendo ativação server-side e quero saber como fazer alguns botões de um CRUD básico, na última fileira, tipo assim:

[image: Print]

Meu código

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php",

            "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]]
        } );
    } );

    </script>
```

E o **server_processing.php**:

```
<?php
$table = 'tbl_medic';
$primaryKey = 'id_Medic';

$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'nome', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'cidade',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'cep',   'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'crm',     'dt' => 3 ),
    array( 'db' => 'email', 'dt' => 4 ),
    array( 'db' => 'pastaDocumentos',     'dt' => 5 )
);

$sql_details = array(
    'user' => '***', //Usuário do banco de dados
    'pass' => '***', //Senha do banco de dados
    'db'   => '***', //Banco de dados
    'host' => 'localhost'
);

require_once( 'ssp.class.php' );
echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Não garanto ser a melhor forma, mas você pode utilizar o [columnDefs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) para realizar essa tarefa:

```
$('#').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php",
    columns: [...],
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": 3, //"Número referente a coluna, startando no 0"
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                //Aqui tem um callback onde pode retornar o botão
                //row - aqui você possui todos os atributos da sua linha
                //Basta criar seu botão e como string e retornar;

                var deleteBtn = '<a type="button" href="/action/metodo/' + row.id + '" ></a>'     
                return deleteBtn;
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Para ficar mais organizada a geração dos botões, te aconelho a criar uma função fábrica para fazer o serviço :)